# wxPython Error in Opening Files in Ubuntu

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, ubuntu-11.10

I'm working on [this tutorial](http://wiki.wxpython.org/Getting%20Started#Windows_or_Frames.3F) and I noticed that this code snippet has a problem with it:

```
def OnOpen(self, e):
    """To open d' files"""
    self.dirname = ""
    dlg = wx.FileDialog(self, "Choose a file", self.dirname, "", "*.*", wx.OPEN)
    if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
        self.filename = dlg.GetFilename()
        self.dirname = dlg.GetDirectory()
        f = open(os.path.join(self.dirname, self.filename))
        self.control.SetValue(f.read())
        f.close()
    dlg.Destroy()
```

I'm running the code in Ubuntu 11.10 and it works as intended as long as you don't attempt to pick a file from the search or recently opened file features.  Apparently it isn't receiving the directory in those cases, as self.dirname is None.  I'm wondering what is happening in GetFilename and how Linux is returning the file directories in the dialog when search or recently used files are selected.

Any insight on this would be appreciated.  Also, if there is anyplace to find the specific code would be appreciated.  I know that it is on my drive, but I have no idea what file its in.

Comment: Take a look in your [site-packages](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/install/?from=olddocs#remove-any-old-versions-of-django) directory. It's highly possible that the important bits are compiled C++ code, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isn't [GetPath](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.FileDialog-class.html#GetPath) the function you'd want to use to get the path and filename of the selected file?

Comment: Yes, apparently so.  I modified the code to use that function rather than GetFilename and GetDirectory.  This seems simpler and it works better, I wonder why the author decided to use the method showed in my question.

Comment: @BrotherJack I read through the Wiki entry and I'm not sure how their approach would work - seems like it depends on the FileDialog setting the default Filename and Directory to the user-selected file, which I'm not seeing in the FileDialog docs.

Comment: `GetDirectory()` has stopped working entirely for this purpose in Ubuntu Quantal. Now it just returns the user's home directory. But `GetPath()` still works correctly.